# "Missing scheme in request url" when using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 44, in process_item
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 109, in get_media_requests
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.IMAGES_URLS_FIELD, [])]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 59, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
```

I wanna get subject_url  for each page, then get image_url for each subject.
I mean i want wo download every imagine from each subject and there is many pages and many subject each page.
I'm suer each url all right
my scrapy code is here:

```
class CaoliuSpider(scrapy.spiders.Spider):

    name = 'Caoliu'
    allowed_dimains = ['bearhk.pw']
    start_urls = []
    base_url = "http://www.examples.com/"
    for i in range(20):
        url = "http://www.examples.com?&page=" + str(i+1)
        start_urls.append(url)

    def parse(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        urls = [ urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url, str(i)) for i in Selector(response=response).xpath('//*[@class="tr3 t_one"]/td/h3/a/@href').extract()]
        for url in urls:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.saveimg)

    def saveimg(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        imgs_urls = Selector(response=response).xpath('//*/input[@type="image"]/@src').extract()
        item = CaoliuItem()
        for url in imgs_urls:
            item['image_urls']  = str(url)
            item['images'] = url
            print item['image_urls']
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a `url` to your `image_urls` field, use `urljoin()`:

```
item['image_urls']  = urlparse.urljoin(self.base_url, url)
```

Also, `allowed_dimains` should be `allowed_domains`.

Answer (score 0):

image_urls should be list, not str.

Scrapy book's example:

```
image_paths = [x[’path’] for ok, x in results if ok]
```